# Parent component does not "catch" emitted event from child component, but it only happens irregularly. What could be the cause for this?

Tags: angular

I have 2 angular components, a parent component and a child component. 
The child component contains a form. On form submit, the child component emits an event with the submitted data. Sometimes the parent component catches the event, sometimes it does not. I can not figure out what could be the reason for that.

**child.component.ts:**

```
  public onSubmit(microservice: Microservice): void {
    if (!this.microserviceCreateForm.valid) {
      return;
    }
    this.onMicroserviceAdded.emit(microservice);
    this.modalService.dismissAll();
  }
```

This code is executed every time the form is submitted.

**parent.component.html:**

```
<app-add-microservice [platform]="platform" [platforms]="platforms"
                              (onMicroserviceAdded)="doAddMicroservice($event)"></app-add-microservice>
```

**parent.component.ts:**

```
  public doAddMicroservice(microservice: Microservice): void {
    this.onMicroserviceAdded.emit(microservice);
  }
```

This code is sometimes executed, sometimes not. What could be the reason for this irregularity? I am not able to accurately reproduce the error, ie I am not able to say what conditions have to be met for it to work/not to work.

Comment: I guess it doen't emit even because microserviceCreateForm is invalid. Did you debug this?

Comment: Yes, every time the event is not "caught" by the parent, the modal closes nonetheless, indicating that the form is valid and the event has been emitted.